# how to combine similar activities in one activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

trying to do the application in android studio. but I have a problem.  For example, mercedes and audi cars have both features such as gasoline and speed. I want to write to a class instead of doing separate classes for Mercedes and audi. I would like to identify brands with similar features from the car class and open them with a button. but I do not know. Can you show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Can You post some code so we can refer to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an activity that has different data for each instance, you can use bundle data to do this.  In your car activity:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context context, String brand, int speed, FuelType fuel)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CarActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_BRAND, brand);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_SPEED, speed);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_FUELTYPE, fuel);
    return intent;
}
```

You then can read these values in onCreate()

You you can launch this activity for the various button pushes like:

```
startActivity(CarActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), "Mercedes", 220, FuelType.Diesel));
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I construe, this is a little more than [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html); this is a matter of data structure design.

Typical inheritance in your case would look so:

```
enum FuelType {
    Petrol, //gasoline
    Diesel,
    Electricity;
}    

class Car {
    FuelType fuelType;
    float speed;
}

class Audi extends Car {}

class Mercedes extends Car {}
```

However, since you want to open up brands with similar features—a sort of "compare products" option on, say, Amazon—the scope of this problem grows beyond mere semantic structuring of the data models; it encompasses the very structuring of data being shown. Include some code to give a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably rather like this:

```
class Manufacturer { ... }

class Car { ... }
```

then you can pass a `carId` to a `CarActivity` or a `manufacturerId` to `ManufacturerActivity`.